# Neo4j: How to use Integer or String with special characters as Identifier/name for a Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to use Integer or String with special characters as Identifier/name for a Node.

For instance I wanted to create this Node with Label as Category:

```
CREATE (000-116880:CATEGORY {PartnerCode:"ABCD12345", MerchantCode:"XXXX_0001", Name:"XXXX ABCDE", Leaf:1, MerchantCategoryID:125})
```

Or

```
CREATE (1234:CATEGORY {PartnerCode:"ABCD12345", MerchantCode:"XXXX_0001", Name:"XXXX ABCDE", Leaf:1, MerchantCategoryID:125})
```

Both these statements fail. So in short, neither am I am able to use '000-116880' as Node name nor am I able to use 1234 as Node identifier/name.

My purpose is to create Node for each category and use its Category-Code as Node name and thereafter assign relationships between categories using their category codes. So I want to have :

```
CREATE (000-116880:CATEGORY {PartnerCode:"ABCD12345", MerchantCode:"XXXX_0001", Name:"XXXX ABCDE", Leaf:1 ,MerchantCategoryID:125})
```

parent of

```
CREATE (000-226880:CATEGORY {PartnerCode:"ABCD12345", MerchantCode:"XXXX_0001", Name:"XXXX ABCDE", Leaf:1 ,MerchantCategoryID:225})
```

Can anyone please give example using Cypher statements.

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks (`) to quote your identifier, label, property name or relationship-type.

```
CREATE (`000-116880`:CATEGORY
        {Leaf:1,
         MerchantCategoryID:125,
         MerchantCode:"XXXX_0001",
         Name:"XXXX ABCDE", 
         PartnerCode:"ABCD12345"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Michael .. However, it does not solve my problem. For instance I use CREATE (`000-116880`:CATEGORY {PartnerCode:"ABCD12345", 
    MerchantCode:"XXXX_0001", Name:"XXXX ABCDE", 
    Leaf:1 ,MerchantCategoryID:125})   to create the node, neo4j still assigns an automated identifier to each node.                                   If I now try to create relationship between 2 nodes using                  (`000-116880`)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(`000-116881`)        Neo4j creates 2 new empty nodes and assign relationship between them . This is completely mystery for me...

Comment: @user3205469 Please don't put code in a comment, it's very hard to read. Instead, edit your question and add the lines from your comment to the bottom; and please format all code properly.